# NLTK: Word not in vocabulary but found in sentence

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to load data from NLTK's Gutenberg dataset. I load the vocabulary from the dataset, excluding any punctuation and use it to create a word to integer mapping dictionary. However, when I later parse the sentences and try to apply the mapping, I get a Key Error because it tries to lookup `'"*'` in the dictionary.

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
import string

def strip_punctuation(sentence):
        return [word.lower() for word in sentence if word not in string.punctuation]

def build_mapping(vocab):
    word_to_int = {}
    for i, word in enumerate(vocab):
        word_to_int[word] = i
    return word_to_int

vocab = set()
for fileid in gutenberg.fileids():
    words = [w.lower() for w in gutenberg.words(fileid) if w not in string.punctuation]
    vocab = vocab.union(words)

word_to_int = build_mapping(vocab)

for fileid in gutenberg.fileids():
    for sentence in gutenberg.sents(fileid):
        sentence = strip_punctuation(sentence)
        for word in sentence:
            x = word_to_int[word] #KeyError: '"*'
```

I understand why this combination of symbols is not caught when I strip away punctuation, but since I am using the same method of stripping punctuation for both the words and the sentences, I am confused by it would appear in the sentences but not in the vocabulary. For the moment, I am checking if a symbol in my vocabulary before I apply the mapping, but I am wondering if there is a better way to strip the punctuation so I can avoid the if statements.

Comment: Your `strip_punctuation` only removes words that are substrings of `string.punctuation`. It doesn't filter out the words that are empty when all the punctuation is removed from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

For python 3

```
sentence = "I can't deal ';with it!**"
characters_to_get_rid_of = ".,':;*!?" #define all characters you don't want
sentence = sentence.translate(str.maketrans("","",characters_to_get_rid_of))
print(sentence)
```

for python 2

```
sentence = "I can't deal ';with it!**"
characters_to_get_rid_of = ".,':;*!?" #define all characters you don't want
sentence = sentence.translate(None,characters_to_get_rid_of)
print sentence
```

Result

```
'i cant deal with it'
```